# Разница между кодами ответов 403 и 401

Tags: http

В чём отличия между этими кодами ответов? Оба говорят об отсутствии прав доступа

Comment: не, 401 однозначнее - пользователь не авторизован, 403 - нет прав доступа к ресурсу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видеть [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.2):

401 Unauthorized:

Если запрос уже включал учетные данные авторизации, то ответ 401 указывает, что авторизация для этих учетных данных была отклонена.

Extracted from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses#:%7E:text=401%20Unauthorized%3A,is%20refusing%20to%20fulfill%20it)

403 Forbidden:

Сервер понял запрос, но отказывается его выполнить.

Edit: [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.2) устарело, см. [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) и [RFC7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235).

Answer (score 7):

- 401: "Вы не авторизованы, сходите авторизуйтесь"
- 403: "Вы не авторизованы, и не будете" или "Вы авторизованы но прав посмотреть вот это всё равно нет"

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Код ответа на статус ошибки "HTTP 403 Forbidden" указывает, что сервер понял запрос, но отказывается его авторизовать.

**Этот статус похож на 401, но в этом случае повторная аутентификация не будет иметь никакого значения.** Доступ запрещен и привязан к логике приложения (например, неверный пароль).

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка 401, Unauthorized - неавторизирован её как правило не генерируют програмно, 401 это один из шагов авторизации. Как правило эта ошибка генерируется отдельной библиотекой управления учётками. Если браузер распознал алгоритм авторизации - он не светит 401, а спрашивает учетные данные. В зависимости от браузера 401 может быть показана после 2-й попытки ввести учетные данные, или 3-ей. Страница посредством 401 будет требовать авторизацию, как правило до тех пор, пока не будет успешной авторизация. 401- используется "windows" авторизацией такой как NTLM, kerberos и т п. Так же может быть использована прозрачная (сквозная) авторизация - тогда браузер тихо обрабатывает ошибку, и вообще ничего не спрашивает, передаёт на сайт данные текущей учетки. Как правило так делают в интрасети.

Ошибка 403 Forbidden - (Запрещено). Как правило - отказано в доступе. Может означать как то, что данному пользователю нельзя читать (обращаться) по данному URL, так и то что вообще никому нельзя читать по данному URL (Иногда служебные папки такие как bin таким образом защищены ).

Так же, не запрещено ошибки програмно генерировать и светить не в том случае для которого они предназначены, но как правило эти две используются для перечисленных целей.